# Asymmetric Nash Bargaining

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, labor-economics, nash-equilibrium, bargaining

The Nash bargaining solution selects the unique solution to the maximization problem $\max_{s_1, s_2 } (s_1 - d_1) (s_2 - d_2)$ such that the solution satisfy the following axioms :

1. Invariance
2. Symmetry
3. Pareto efficiency
4. Independence of irrelevant alternatives

Does replacing the maximization problem by $\max_{s_1, s_2 } (s_1 - d_1)^{\alpha}  (s_2 - d_2)^{1-\alpha}$  (i.e. give different bargaining power to the players) change the list of axioms satisfied by the former maximization problem ? From my understanding symmetry will be no longer be satisfied, but does that affect other axioms as well?

Comment: Please be more clear. What kind of axioms are you referring to, axioms related to what?  (and I would suggest to edit your question rather than reply to this comment)

Comment: Hello Alecos, the post has been edited. Thank you.

Comment: I will probably provide an answer here, but you can find everything in the book,  Roth A. E. (1979). Axiomatic models of bargaining.

Comment: I believe, it depends on the choice of restrictions on $\alpha$. If $\alpha \ge 0$, then for some zero weights there may not be enough "pressure" on maximizing all components and Pareto efficiency may fail. If instead, $\alpha > 0$, the solution is stronger and does not include corner points where some players get exactly the disagreement payoff (this property is sometimes called Strong Individual Rationality).